# Show that in a commutative ring with characteristic $2$ : $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2=(x-y)^2$

Tags: ring-theory

Show that in a commutative ring with characteristic $2$ : $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2=(x-y)^2$.

I need some pointers to solve this.

Comment: What happens when you multiply out the squares $(x\pm y)^2$?

Comment: 2 = 0 and therefore -1 = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $xy+xy=0$. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: i know $xy=yx$ and $x+x=0$ and $y+y=0$ . how does this add up to give this result ?

Comment: $(x\pm y)^2=(x\pm y)(x\pm y)=x^2\pm 2xy+y^2$.

Comment: oh !! I was missing that $\forall x,y\in R, xy\in R$ ..lol. Thanks a lot !!